# Migrating Jackson JSON from Wildfly to Tomee

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, wildfly, apache-tomee

Given this class annotated with Jackson:

```
public class ResponseMsg implements Serializable{
    
    public ResponseMsg(String ret, String msg){
        this.returnCode = ret;
        this.errorMsg = msg;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("ret")
    private int returnCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("msg")
    private String errorMessage;

    // .... getters and setters
}
```

I have this class working *fine* in Wildfly 26, it returns a JSON response with the annotated attributes of ResponseMsg:

```
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response processMessage() {

    @POST
    @Path("/proc")
    public Response process() {
        ResponseMsg er = new ResponseMsg("abc","some message");
        return Response.ok(er).build();
    }

 }
```

Since it's annotated with the JsonProperty, I'm getting in the browser as expected:

```
{ "ret": "abc", "msg": "some message" }
```

Now, I'm migrating to Tomee with Jakarta EE 9.1, and the same code returns the ResponseMsg but *without* the annotated properties, the JSON looks like this:

```
{ "returnCode": "abc", "errorMessage": "some message" }
```

Something is missing in Tomee's configuration, what is it?

Comment: FWIW WildFly 27 implements Jakarta EE 10 and you can enable Jackson support for REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Jakarta Documentation,

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/2.0/jakarta-jsonb-spec-2.0.html#customizing-property-names

> There are two standard ways how to customize serialization of field
> (or JavaBean property) to JSON document. The same applies to
> deserialization. The first way is to annotate field (or JavaBean
> property) with jakarta.json.bind.annotation.JsonbProperty annotation.
> The second option is to set
> jakarta.json.bind.config.PropertyNamingStrategy.

You need to use the `@JsonBProperty` annotation, instead of JsonProperty that you are using.

```
import jakarta.json.bind.annotation.JsonbProperty;
```

Comment: My application is large and complex, and uses Jackson extensively, what I put in the question is just an example, there's no way to use Jackson with Jakarta EE?

Comment: I think you will need to change them if you want to use JakartaEE.  You can also take a look at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jakarta-rs-providers and see if it can help in anyway?

Comment: I didn't find a way to keep the code unchanged, thanks for the direction